# Is spark more efficient than map-reduce for running a bunch of sequential processing tasks?

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce

I have a MapReduce job which works perfectly fine. I wonder can I benefit by rewriting it to Spark and will it be significant difference, like twice of the previous performance for example? My MapReduce job doesn't have a reducer it just transforms data, there is no sophisticated computations, there is no iterative operations on the same input data, so it seems like Spark in-memory features are useless in my case.

What also worries me is that with MapReduce I don't need to set the amount of memory and the number of executors needed for job to be done, they will be calculated from the size of input data. While in case with Spark I will have to use `spark.executor.memory` and `num-executors`, dynamic allocation has some troubles on our cluster.

Comment: There's a lot of factors that go into this, so there is no definite "yes, it will go faster"

Comment: What are those factors? I can be more specific, I guess.

Comment: The format of the data you are shuffling around, how much memory the cluster has, etc. You say that "Spark in-memory features are useless", but Spark is an in-memory framework, so your data will be transformed there. If all you are doing is transforming data, then why not try it and see if you can get a speed difference?

Comment: We have about 7T of memory, the job transforms HFiles -> Avro. Yes, I'm gonna try it but I just wanted to make sure that theoretically I'm right and Spark brings no advantages in my case, because to just read data from disk, transform it without inter-node communication and write it back row by row, you dont't need RDDs and DataFrames.

Comment: As soon as you read a file into Spark, you have an RDD, though

Comment: Yeah, that's why I think it doesn't have any advantages of using Spark here, I don't need to load some huge amount of data in memory and process it, I can process my data line by line. It's just that I'm new to Spark and I want third party opinion on this matter, everyone around at my place is so used to Spark they don't know much about MapReduce.